# IOS: Make Notifications with Repeat Trigger only show up when device is unlocked?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to create a notification that repeats every 60 seconds, as in:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(
  timeInterval: 60,
  repeats: true
)
```

But this makes the notifications still appear even when the phone is locked.

Is there is a way to limit the notifications to repeat only when the device is unlocked?